# c# using LINQ, string.contains dictionay key

Tags: c#, linq

How to achive value using LINQ expression:
I want to get the value from Dictionary where key is the "6VLX130T" from the file name or string name (e.g file name is  E8502813B2-1PA_6VLX130T_XAPT2K3_100C_Indu_Class_20140408052219.stdf)

or to say in other words, i want to check whether the string contains any key from the dictionary and then get the value for that key.

```
Dictionary<string, string> device = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        device.Add("6VLX130T", "VIRTEX6");
        device.Add("6VLX140T", "VIRTEX6");
        device.Add("ZYNQ40", "ZYNQ");

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            if (file.IndexOf("_") > 0)
            {
                //E8502813B2-1PA_6VLX130T_XAPT2K3_100C_Indu_Class_20140408052219.stdf(this is file name)
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                string [] split = fi.Name.Split('_');
                foreach (string words in split)
                {
                    if(device.ContainsKey(words))
                    {
                        var valuee = device.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains(words)).Value;

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get out of the Dictionary?

Comment: I am looping through the file and the file name has the key (not the full file name as the key) only the file name sub string is the key (E8502813B2-1PA_6VLX130T_XAPT2K3_100C_Indu_Class_20140408052219.stdf). key in this file name is 6VLX130T. so i want to find the value from dictionary that matches with 6VLX130T.

Comment: string [] split = fi.Name.Split('_'); is it possbile using lamda expression to find the value from the dictionary, without splitting the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only ever have one 'key' in your file names, you can write:

```
string value;
foreach (string words in split)
{
    if (device.TryGetValue(words, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

If you do not want to return, do something else useful with value, hard to tell exactly what you need to do by the question.

To specifically use a LINQ expression (which I do not think aids readability in this case), you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
var matchingKeyName = file.Split('_')
    .Where(s => device.ContainsKey(s)).SingleOrDefault();
if (matchingKeyName != null)
{
    string value = device[matchingKeyName];
    return value;
}
else
{
    // key name not found in file
}
```

This assumes that the key name is only ever included in the file name once at most. If there are more than one key in the file, an exception is thrown.

If you want to take this to the extreme and write a one line lambda expression, then you can do this, but I really do not think that LINQ is the right approach for this as below, as the code is nowhere near as easy to understand.

`var resultValue = devices.Single(x => x.Key == file.Split('_').Where(s => devices.ContainsKey(s)).SingleOrDefault());`